# MvvmCross.Forms - Default Spinner will not exit

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvmcross, mvxlistview

This bug exists in the Sample files (StarWarsSample) and I have been trying to remove it for SEVERAL hours... any advice is appreciated:

Using MvvmCross.Forms

I have an MvxListView which has RefreshCommand bound to a command. I have confirmed it fires. When the MvxListView is pulled down **(both iOS and Android)** a spinner appears. However it never disappears. I do not have any exceptions being thrown. If I raise a dialog it appears over the spinner, but then once cancelled the spinner remains. My ListView is dynamically updating fine. Just the spinner never disappears... I'm assuming it's coming from some specific function in MVVMCross/Forms but i cannot seem to find any reference to it.

Here's the relevant code (in it's current state after trying different approaches)

```
 <views:MvxListView 
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            SelectionMode="None"
            ItemsSource="{mvx:MvxBind BtDevices}" 
            ItemClick="{mvx:MvxBind BtDeviceSelectedCommand}"
            IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" 
            RefreshCommand="{mvx:MvxBind RefreshBtDevicesCommand}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DeviceNameTemplate}"
            RowHeight="{x:OnPlatform Android=55, iOS=55, UWP=40}"
            BackgroundColor="LightBlue"
            SeparatorVisibility="None">
           
        </views:MvxListView>
```

---

```
 public HomeViewModel(...){
BtDevices = new MvxObservableCollection<BtDevice>();

        BtDeviceSelectedCommand = new MvxAsyncCommand<IBtDevice>(BtDeviceSelected);
        FetchBtDevicesCommand = new MvxCommand(() =>
        { 
            FetchBtDeviceTask = MvxNotifyTask.Create(LoadDevices, onException: OnException);
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => FetchBtDeviceTask);
        });

        RefreshBtDevicesCommand = new MvxCommand(()=>
        {
            RefreshDeviceTask = MvxNotifyTask.Create(RefreshBtDevices, OnException);
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => RefreshDeviceTask);
        });
}
 private async Task RefreshBtDevices()
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        var result = await _btService.LoadDevices(_nextPage);

        foreach (var d in result.Where(d => BtDevices.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == d.Id) == null))
        {
            BtDevices.Add(d);
        }

        IsBusy = false;

        await RaisePropertyChanged(() => RefreshDeviceTask);
        await RaisePropertyChanged(() => RefreshBtDevicesCommand);
        
    }
```

Comment: Forgot to mention MvvmCross and MvvmCross.Forms V7.1.2 (latest stable)

Comment: Ok.. so i JUST noticed that i was using MvxCommand instead of MvxAsyncCommand. Which i changed... HOWEVER, now the spinner immediately disappears and the listview will not refresh a second time...

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.listview.isrefreshing?view=xamarin-forms) you need to bind the `IsRefreshing` property of the list view.

> Gets or sets a value that tells whether the list view is currently refreshing

Something like this:

```
IsRefreshing="{mvx:MvxBind IsBusy}"
```

or if you are using an `MvxNotifyTask`:

```
IsRefreshing="{mvx:MvxBind RefreshDeviceTask.IsNotCompleted}"
```

[Here](https://www.xamarinhelp.com/pull-to-refresh-listview/) you have more informaion, even though it uses directly `ListView` on the example the same can be applied to `MvxListView` given that it inherits from `ListView`.

HIH

Comment: Thanks i don't know why i didn't get notified of this till just now! I gave up on the sample and worked out different approach. I don't know the protocol if i can't confirm this as the answer since i can't test it... I DO appreciate the response though and am very sorry I didn't see this before!